# Webscarab editing issue

Tags: jvm, ubuntu-14.04, webscarab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKlY9.png)

Hello everyone I think I have a pretty unique issue here with Webscarab. Downloaded it and installed fine on ubuntu w/ 
java -jar webscarab-installer-20070504-1631.jar (found on sourceforge)
it's configured fine and it is monitoring traffic, but every time I try to manually edit an intercepted request it will pop up a hidden window w/ the request(you can see three dots in the bottom left of the image to indicate the main window and two others are open).  The problem is I cannot open that window, I'll try to click on one of the 'edit requests' when i right click that button, but it won't open them. it just keeps showing me that manual edit page.  I tried reinstalling didn't fix it. java version is 1.7.0_85. Please help!

Comment: also sorry, first post, no image description. just 'enter image description here'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so not a direct answer, but is there any particular reason you are using Webscarab?
That tool hasnt been updated for many years :/

Not too surprisingly I'd recommend you using OWASP ZAP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ZAP which is the most actively maintained open source web security tool.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: Hello Simon, I was using Webscarab, because I installed WebGoat 6.0 (which I realize might also be a little dated itself), and it was one of the proxies/spiders it recommended.  The other two were Paros & Burp.  I will definitely check out your tool, and hopefully when 7.0 is released it will recommend ZAP.